# Creating templates in Django / Python

Tags: python, django

I am learning `Django` and I tried to create a template like this:

```
>>> weekend = True
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> template_string = """
{% if weekend %}
    <p> This is a weekend </p>
{% endif %}
"""
>>> t = Template(template_string)
```

I get this following error. Am I missing something?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    t = Template(template_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 106, in __init__
    if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Thanks!

Comment: "ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined."  Seems pretty clear. Are you following the official Django tutorial?  If not, what tutorial are you following?

Comment: Yes, I am using the book from `djangobook.com`. Sorry, my bad. Missed it out. Just started `IDLE` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates.

Start your shell by doing `python manage.py shell` from the directory containing `manage.py` and `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've started a django project try running the same code inside a django shell.

```
python manage.py shell
```

Alternatively set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to the name of your settings module. If you're using linux and running things from the directory where the settings.py file is then you can just do

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

If you're using linux (or another unix based OS) and you want to run from a different directory you'll need to make sure your project directory is in the python path. Then you can do

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings"
```